# Do nothing and throw an error if condition is not met

Tags: rust

At the moment I'm running a `panic!` macro every time I the extension is not met. But this is not how it should be, I want it to just throw an error and/or skip and do nothing. Is there a way to throw an error instead and/or skip it.

```
impl FileMetaData {
  fn new(path: &str) -> FileMetaData {
    
    FileMetaData {
      name: FileMetaData::get_file_name(&path).to_string(),
      directory: FileMetaData::is_directory(&path),
      path: path.to_string(),
    }
  }

  fn get_file_name(path: &str) -> &str {
    let file_path = Path::new(path);
    let file_name_os_str = file_path.file_stem().unwrap();
    if !FileMetaData::is_directory(path) {
      if file_path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap() != "heic" {
        // TO DO: Change to Err or skip if file not supported
        // TO DO: Possible change the whole flow of converting the image
        panic!("File format not supported");
      }
    }
    return file_name_os_str.to_str().unwrap()
  }

  fn is_directory(path: &str) -> bool {
    Path::new(&path).is_dir() 
  }
}
```

I have 2 use case on the `FileMetaData` struct since I'm accepting 2 kind of path, a file and a directory.

For file, it's easier since I can just throw an error and it would exit.

But for directory, I need it to not exit if there is a unsupported format detected.

```
# file
let file = FileMetaData::new(&file_path);

# directory
let entries = fs::read_dir(&path)?
    .map(|res| res.map(|e| e.path()))
    .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, io::Error>>()?;

for entry in entries {
    let file_path = file.to_str().unwrap();
    # this should just print an error and continue for the
    # other entries in list
    let file_metadata = FileMetaData::new(&file_path);
}
```

Comment: What does "throw an error and continue" mean? Where should the error be "thrown", and when should the code which receives it execute, if not immediately?

Comment: For example, if I'm looping from the list of entries, it should just throw an error that the file being read is not supported and continue the loop without that "entry". It executes depending on the given path, if it's a file I can get a way with it easily but my problem is if the path given is a directory I would loop on each file to know if they are supported or not.

Comment: What *specifically* do you want your program's behaviour to be when an error occurs? "Throwing" means ending control of the current code, it is mutually exclusive with continuing. It is like you said you want your function to return but still continue executing, or you want your program to stop but also not stop.

Comment: Ok, I think using the word "throwing" isn't  the right word. I just want it to let me know that the file is not supported and continue generating a list if the path given is a directory.

Comment: So you want to print an error message?

Comment: Yes, I supposed so since `panic!` is not the appropriate way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`continue`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.continue.html) to skip to the next iteration of a loop.

## Method 1: Using [`let-else`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html)

```rust
for entry in entries {
    let Ok(data) = might_fail() else {
        eprintln!("An error occurred!");
        continue;
    };
}
```

Downsides: `Err` is not exposed to the error handling block.

## Method 2: Using [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.match.html)

```rust
for entry in entries {
    let data = match might_fail() {
        Ok(data) => data,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("An error occurred: {e}");
            continue;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This is a good one if I'm only dealing with a directory where I loop through files paths. The problem is I also need to do the same with a single file path which doesn't use a loop. That's why I moved it to `impl` block.

Comment: @nsantiago2719 I'm not sure how the program should 'continue' If the single file path operation fails, with the provided informations. However, I think you should propagate the error by changing the return type of the function `get_file_name` and `new` to a `Result`, and you can handle that with methods mentioned above or you can just use the [`? operator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator) to let the main function handle the error with [`Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html) trait.